# HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected (HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: ) elasticsearch docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, elasticsearch, httpclient

I've set up elasticsearch locally through docker container using this reference successfully

[https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/configuring-tls-docker.html](https://stackoverflow.com)

but when i try to use elasticsearch in my rails console. i am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2: from (irb):9
1: from (irb):9:in `rescue in irb_binding'
HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected (HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: )
```

the server started successfully although the browser is showing the connection is insecure.
[https://localhost:9200]
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khPMe.png)
is successfully showing elasticsearch status but when i try http [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDioT.png) its not loading